# How do I set signature PDF in PdfButtonFormField as signature - Itext7 Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, pdf-generation, itext7

I need to get signature from pdf1 and store it inside 2nd pdf in PdfButtonFormField

I tried below solutions so far -

```
PdfButtonFormField signature = (PdfButtonFormField) form.getField("Image2_af_image");
File signPdfFile = new File(String.valueOf(Paths.get(SIGNATURE_PDF)));
ByteArrayInputStream signByteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(signPdfFile.toPath()));
final PdfDocument signatureDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(signByteArray));
//1        
PdfFormXObject signn = signatureDoc.getFirstPage().copyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
//2        
String signText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(signatureDoc.getFirstPage());
```

This is the pdf template, need to put content of pdf1 into Applicant's signature, how can I achieve this ? -

[image]

Comment: *"I need to get signature from pdf1 and store it inside 2nd pdf"* (you are aware that this will invalidate the signature?) *"in PdfButtonFormField"* (PDF signatures are already a form field type, how do you want to put a field into another?) *"I tried below solutions so far"* (does that solution do what you want?) *"This is the pdf template, need to put content of pdf1 into Applicant's signature, how can I achieve this ?"* (Above you said you needed to take a *signature from pdf1*, now you say *the content*. So which do you mean, please clarify.)

Comment: @mkl Basically I want to convert PDF signature into image format and attach it into another PDF

Comment: Ok, so you only want the in-document appearance of a signature field from pdf1, you explicitly don't want the embedded digital signature itself. Right? And you want to put that appearance into a 2nd document. Originally you said "in PdfButtonFormField", so you want to re-use the appearance of that signature field in pdf1 as appearance of a pushbutton in the second pdf. Right? And does the target pushbutton already exist (so only the appearance shall be applied) or has it to be created?

Comment: @mkl yes you are right, the target pushbotton is already exist as part of the pdf template